# Retrofit + rx error handling in map

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to handle error in my map if response is not successfull. I've tried to use RetrofitException from this article [Error handling in Retrofit](http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html) but unsuccesfull.

This is my Observable

```
    public Observable<JsonElement> commonResponse(final Object request, String method, final Context context) {

    Log.v("method", method);
    //Create Request
    Map<String, Object> data = ApiHelper.commonParams(request, method, context);

    return apiService.commonResponse(method, data)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .map(new Func1<Response<BaseResponse>, JsonElement>() {
                @Override
                public JsonElement call(Response<BaseResponse> response) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        //throwException(response);                            

                    }

                    BaseResponse baseResponse = response.body();
                    return baseResponse.getData();
                }
            });

}
```

This is my Retrofit

```
    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiService.API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create());

public static Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.addInterceptor(logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC)).build()).build();

public static ApiService retrofitCreate() {
    return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **subscribe** to you Observerable I think will fix your problem. At the end you method add **subscribe**:

```
              .subscribe(new Subscriber<YOUR_OBJECT>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        //handle your error here
                        showError();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(YOUR_OBJECT object) {
                    }
```

See more [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html).

Comment: I have **subscribe** and it is in another class. I need to pass throwable from map to onError.

Comment: @AlexCrow put in try catch and Observer.error(t) doesn't fix your issue?